# Debugging JBehave scenarios

Tags: java, debugging, testing, bdd

I'm having trouble debugging my jbehave tests.  I cannot get maven to start the jbehave tests and stop at a breakpoint.  I have this in my pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
     <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
   <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>run-scenarios-found</id>
       <phase>test</phase>
       <configuration>
         <scenarioIncludes>
           <scenarioInclude>**/scenario/**/*${test}.java</scenarioInclude>
         </scenarioIncludes>
         <scenarioExcludes>
           <scenarioExclude>**/*Steps.java</scenarioExclude>
         </scenarioExcludes>
       </configuration>
       <goals>
         <goal>run-scenarios</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and I have tried things like:

```
$  mvn -e -o -Dtest=MyTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" clean test
```

and

```
$ export MVN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" ; mvn -Dtest=MyTest clean test
```

I can try to use [jsadebugd](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jsadebugd.html), but I that will probably require immaculate timing to automate, so that sounds like a suboptimal solution, and I feel like the JBehave Maven plugin should provide this functionality.  Clearly I have just not found the right piece of documetation yet.  Any ideas how I go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE"

then start my mvn tests:
mvn install

(maven now hangs waiting for the debugger to connect)

Then start Eclipse in a remote debug session, pointing at local host, port 8787 (as above), with appropriate breakpoints set.

Comment: For me Maven waits for  Eclipse to connect as it should, then Maven continues but it does not stop in break points.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier not to start the tests with maven, but rather in the IDE with JUnit? Then you can use the debugger directly? I normally do it so, that the CI server uses maven to execute JBehave, but in the IDE, I prefer a more direct way of execution.

Comment: Not if the tests have to run on a different machine than your IDE

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. In Eclipse **Run** -> **Debug Configurations...**
2. Select **Maven Build** and click **New** button
3. Set the goals (`clean very` in my case) and possible parameters
4. Hit **Debug** button

Answer (score -1):

mvn -e -o -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" integration-test

This line worked perfect for me. Setup your Jbehave project in eclipse 
with the debug port (8787) and connect to the debugger quickly while mvn is waiting to connect to your eclipse project.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as one of the existing answers. What's the point of repeating everything it says?