# JBehave Maven RunningStoriesFailed exception

Tags: java, maven, jbehave, jbehave-maven-plugin

I'm using JBehave and Maven to test a Spring MVC application. I am running the code below with a single story file. My problem is that I constantly get a `StoryExecutionFailed` error and I don't know why or how to fix it.

There is something suspicious with the way I am configuring JBehave, because I don't see some of my options actually being printed to output (example: output shows default timeout of 300 seconds but I've clearly set it to 10000 in code). Yet my story class is indeed running, because I see output printed to screen if I add `System.out.println()`'s. I am also suspicious that the story steps are not being mapped, because usually I'd see the steps code printed in output.

I'm hoping someone can help troubleshoot, because I don't know where to begin debugging this.

What I have checked so far:

- Story text matches the annotations in my step class
- Class qualifier in the spring context matches the actual class qualifier
- Spring Annotations are in the right places (@Component)
- Story paths are not null or empty (I printed these out in the `storyPaths()` method, printing omitted from this post)

EDIT: I have tried attaching Eclipse to a remote-debug session [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731023/debugging-jbehave-scenarios), but even though maven waits for it to attach none of my breakpoints stop execution.

I start my tests like this:

```
mvn clean package
```

The error I see is this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior.stories.APIStories
Processing system properties {}
Using controls EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=false,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeouts=300,threads=1,failOnStoryTimeout=false]
Running story stories/PROJ/PROJ-689.story
Using timeout for story PROJ-689.story of 300 secs.
Generating reports view to 'C:\Users\acymmer\Projects\myproject\target\jbehave' using formats '[ide_console, html, stats]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.584 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior.stories.APIStories
run(com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior.stories.APIStories)  Time elapsed: 1.574 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in running stories:
stories/PROJ/PROJ-689.story: org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$StoryExecutionFailed: stories/PROJ/PROJ-689.story
        at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed.handleFailures(Embedder.java:553)
        at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.handleFailures(Embedder.java:238)
        at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:216)
        at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.run(JUnitStories.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error:
  APIStories>JUnitStories.run:20 ▒ RunningStoriesFailed Failures in running stor...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.919 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-04T16:47:58-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/374M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project MyProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\acymmer\Projects\myproject\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Scenario file text:

```
Scenario: Run a JBehave test successfully
Given this jbehave scenario
When mvn integration-test is run
Then expect success
```

Story class:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior.stories;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.embedder.EmbedderControls;
import org.jbehave.core.failures.PassingUponPendingStep;
import org.jbehave.core.failures.PendingStepStrategy;
import org.jbehave.core.i18n.LocalizedKeywords;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryLoader;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTableFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.parsers.RegexStoryParser;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StepdocReporter;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporter;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterControls;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters.DateConverter;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters.ExamplesTableConverter;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.spring.SpringApplicationContextFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.spring.SpringStepsFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior.infrastructure.JiraCredentials;
import com.jbehaveforjira.javaclient.JiraStepDocReporter;
import com.jbehaveforjira.javaclient.JiraStoryReporter;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


/**
 * Configuration for running JBehave stories.
 * This class contains configuration for running stories and reporting results to Jira.
 */
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:jbehave-app-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class APIStories extends JUnitStories {

    private JiraCredentials jiraCredentials = new JiraCredentials();

    public APIStories() { }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        ParameterConverters parameterConverters = new ParameterConverters();
        ExamplesTableFactory examplesTableFactory = new ExamplesTableFactory(
                new LocalizedKeywords(),
                new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()),
                parameterConverters);
        parameterConverters.addConverters(
                new DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                new ExamplesTableConverter(examplesTableFactory));
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(CreateStoryReportBuilder())
                .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(examplesTableFactory))
                .useStoryLoader(CreateStoryLoader())
                .useStepdocReporter(CreateStepdocReporter())
                .useParameterControls(CreateParameterControls())
                .useParameterConverters(parameterConverters)
                .usePendingStepStrategy(new PassingUponPendingStep());
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new SpringApplicationContextFactory("jbehave-app-context.xml")
                .createApplicationContext();
        return new SpringStepsFactory(configuration(), appContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
                CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(),
                asList("**/" + System.getProperty("storyFilter", "*") + ".story"),
                null);  //no excludes
    }

    private StoryReporterBuilder CreateStoryReportBuilder() {
        StoryReporterBuilder b = new StoryReporterBuilder() {
            public StoryReporter reporterFor(String storyPath, org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format format) {
                if (format.equals(org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.HTML)) {
                    return new JiraStoryReporter(
                            new File("target", "story_report.xml"),
                            keywords(),
                            jiraCredentials.GetUrl(),
                            jiraCredentials.GetProject(),
                            jiraCredentials.GetUserName(),
                            jiraCredentials.GetPassword(),
                            jiraCredentials.GetEnvironment());
                } else {
                    return super.reporterFor(storyPath, format);
                }
            }
        };
        b = b.withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()))
                .withFailureTrace(true)
                .withFormats(Format.IDE_CONSOLE, Format.HTML, Format.STATS);
        return b;
    }

    public StoryLoader CreateStoryLoader() {
        return new LoadFromClasspath(APIStories.class);
    }

    public StepdocReporter CreateStepdocReporter() {
        return new JiraStepDocReporter(
                jiraCredentials.GetUrl(),
                jiraCredentials.GetProject(),
                jiraCredentials.GetUserName(),
                jiraCredentials.GetPassword());
    }

    public EmbedderControls CreateEmbedderControls() {
        return new EmbedderControls()
                .doSkip(true) //allows use of the @skip meta annotation on stories?
                .doIgnoreFailureInStories(false)
                .doIgnoreFailureInView(true)
                .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
                .doVerboseFailures(true)
                .doVerboseFiltering(true)
                .useStoryTimeouts("10000"); //temporarily ensure timeouts are not an issue
    }

    public ParameterControls CreateParameterControls() {
        return new ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(true);
    }
}
```

Relevant bits from my POM (note that we are using this in the Test scope, in the same module as the actual application):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/mycompany/myproject/test/behavior/stories/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-stories</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/mycompany/myproject/test/behavior/stories/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>java.awt.headless</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <threads>1</threads>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <metaFilters>
                            <metaFilter>-skip</metaFilter>
                        </metaFilters>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-stepdocs</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/mycompany/myproject/test/behavior/stories/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>report-stepdocs-as-embeddables</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
">
<!-- =============================================================================================================== -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myproject.test.behavior" />
</beans>
```

And finally my steps class:

```
@Component
public class EmptyJBehaveSteps {

    @BeforeStory
    public void BeforeStoryStarts() { }

    @Given("this jbehave scenario")
    public void Given() { }

    @When("mvn integration-test is run")
    public void When() { }

    @Then("expect success")
    public void Then() { }

    @AfterStory
    public void AfterStoryEnds() { }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not find a satisfactory answer, and I no longer work for this client so I can't go back to the code. However, I did narrow at least part of the problem to JBehave's advertised "out-in" config precedence (see the last green box at http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/configuration.html ). Another pending problem came from the JiraReporter, part of a third party package which updates jira stories with jbehave output, which seems to need to download stories from jira instead of using paths from local configuration.

Answer (score 0):

use `maven-surefire-plugin version` `2.19.1`, add this code `<version>2.19.1</version>` into `maven-surefire-plugin`. If you want to install the lib anyway you can run mvn clean install -DskipTests. and Right Click on project -> "Run as Maven Test". This will automatically download the missing plugin. & after that, Right Click on project ->"Update Maven project" it removes the error